# CS0103: the name does not exist in current Context?

Tags: c#, validation, model-view-controller, contacts

I'm not sure why, as the method works in other projects that I've made (as far as I can see)

But for some reason it keeps saying that the name "Mail..." does not exist in current context, which I don't understand.

So if someone could clarify why this is happening, and how to fix it I would be most grateful!

The problem seems to appear when I'm trying to validate the inputs in my contact form.

(Originally I wanted to models one for Contacts, and one for the tables in the SQL, but I couldn't get it to work properly)

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Kontakt()
{
    var ViewModel = new Fisk.Models.ALL();

    ViewModel.Kontakt = db.web_Kontakt.FirstOrDefault();
    ViewModel.Kategori = db.site_Kategorier.FirstOrDefault();

    ViewModel.kategorier = db.site_Kategorier.ToList();

    List<site_Kategorier> kategorier = new List<site_Kategorier>();

    return View(ViewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Kontakt(Fisk.Models.ALL myMail)
{
    var ViewModel = new Fisk.Models.ALL();

    ViewModel.Kontakt = db.web_Kontakt.FirstOrDefault();
    ViewModel.Kategori = db.site_Kategorier.FirstOrDefault();

    ViewModel.kategorier = db.site_Kategorier.ToList();

    List<site_Kategorier> kategorier = new List<site_Kategorier>();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        SendMail(myMail);
    }

    return View(ViewModel);
}

public void SendMail(Fisk.Models.ALL myMail)
{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

    // Afsender
    mail.From = new MailAddress(myMail.MailEmail);

    // Besvarelsen sendes til... 
    mail.ReplyToList.Add(myMail.MailEmail);

    // Emne / overskrift 
    mail.Subject = "Fisk:" + myMail.MailOverskrift;

    // Modtager 
    mail.To.Add("webtestmastermail@gmail.com");

    // Mail body
    mail.Body = myMail.MailNavn + myMail.MailBesked.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />");

    // HTML = tillader HTML
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

    //Teknisk afsendelse
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

    //Udbyders mailhost
    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

    // Port
    smtp.Port = 587;
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

    // Email + Password
    smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("webtestmastermail@gmail.com", "***");

    // Send
    smtp.Send(mail);
}
```

Models:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Fisk.Models
{
    public class ALL
    {

        public List<front_Slider> Slider { get; set; }
        public List<front_TekstBoks> tekstBoks { get; set; }
        public List<site_Kategorier> kategorier { get; set; }

        public List<site_Product> products { get; set; }

        public web_Kontakt Kontakt { get; set; }
        public site_Kategorier Kategori { get; set; }

        public site_Product o_product { get; set; }


        // NAVN
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Fejl: Der mangler at indsætte et navn")]
        public string MailNavn { get; set; }

        // EMAIL
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Fejl: Der skal indsætte en e-mail")]
        public string MailEmail { get; set; }

        // EMNE
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Fejl: Der mangler en overskrift for beskeden")]
        public string MailOverskrift { get; set; }

        // BESKED
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Fejl: Der mangler en tekst for beskeden ")]
        public string MailBesked { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model Fisk.Models.ALL

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Kontakt";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="k_container conAll">
    <h2>Kontakt Fisk.nu</h2>

    <form action="/Home/Kontakt" method="post">
        <label for="MailNavn">Navn:</label>
        <input type="text" id="MailNavn" name="MailNavn">
        <p>@Html.ValidationMessage(MailNavn)</p>>

        <label for="MailEmail">E-mail:</label>
        <input type="text" id="MailEmail" name="MailEmail">
        <p>@Html.ValidationMessage(MailEmail)</p>

        <label for="MailOverskrift">Emne:</label>
        <input type="text" id="MailOverskrift" name="MailOverskrift">
        <p>@Html.ValidationMessage(MailOverskrift)</p>

        <textarea name="MailBesked" id="MailBesked"></textarea>
        <p>@Html.ValidationMessage(MailBesked)</p>
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send" />
    </form>

    <div id="mapCon">
        <div id="mapFrame">
            <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2222.554893407964!2d10.211985315916563!3d56.14750998066078!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x0!2zNTbCsDA4JzUxLjAiTiAxMMKwMTInNTEuMCJF!5e0!3m2!1sda!2sdk!4v1551903974778" width="400" height="320" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        <p>GPS: 56.14751, 10.214174</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you try to condense your example a bit? You've provided nearly 150 lines of code, but you haven't specified the precise error message or where it occurs... that makes it harder for us to help you. If the problem is in the view, perhaps it's just that you want `@Model.MailBesked` instead of `MailBesked` etc?

Comment: You are using MailMessage class and I hope you have System.Net.Mail in your usings. If not add it and let us know if it resolves your issue

Comment: It's already in.

Comment: Its all of my @Model.Mail.. there doesn't seem to go through. The problem is that the project cannot "find" the name, even tho the name has already been clarified in the Model.ALL

Comment: The name "Mail..."  does not occur in your code. Post the literal error message and make clear to which line it belongs.

Comment: its not literally the name "Mail.." its just a short form, instead of listing all the MailMessage, MailName, MailOverskrift, MailMessage. 


Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0103 The name 'MailBesked' does not exist in the current context Fisk C:\Users\idax3822\Documents\Eksamen\Fisk\Fisk\Views\Home\Kontakt.cshtml 25 Active
(Same error occurs for the other validations)